# How to use StringFormat in StringFormat of a MultiBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I try to re-use an existing StringFormat "within" the StringFormat of a MultiBinding.
Code looks like this:

```
<MultiBinding StringFormat="Test {0}, {1}, {2}">
    <Binding Path="FirstString" />
    <Binding Path="SecondString" />
    <Binding Path="ThirdString" StringFormat="{StaticResource ExistingFormat} />
</MultiBinding>
```

But the StringFormat of "ThirdString" does never get applied. Does anyone now how I could get this to work, or is this not possible?
By the way, the existing StringFormat i try to use is defined like this:
`<sys:String x:Key="ExistingFormat">{0:#,#0.00}</sys:String>`

Comment: This won't work because the target of ThirdBinding is not a string property. You will have to do the formatting by a Binding Converter, or just integrate it into the MultiBinding's StringFormat: `StringFormat="Test {0}, {1}, {2:#,#0.00}"`

Comment: ah yes, of course. Works now with a converter. Shouldn't code before the first coffee in the morning, I guess.
Thanks a lot!